# Hash table insert and remove element

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I'm trying to do a Hash table with linear probing insertion.

The size of the table is 11, my hash function is, h(k) = k mod 11, and what i want to do is.

Insert(15,c)
Insert(4,a)
Insert(26,b) 
Delete(15)
Insert(5,d)
Insert(4,e)

Here is my solution but it aint right.

[image]

It is supposed to be like this, can someone explain why?

[image]

Comment: Probably because there's a bug in your code. But unless you show us your code, all we can do is say something like "you didn't implement your linear probing correctly." Or, come to think of it, you're not correctly detecting the duplicate key `4`, so rather than overwriting the `4,a` that's in position 5, you're probing for the first open space and putting it there.

Comment: I'm not coding this, I'm practicing for an exam and this was one of the questions. You mean the answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, you clarified your question.

The answer is correct.

Your solution is incorrect because when you do the `insert(4,e)`, you're not first checking to see if that key already exists in the hash table. If it does exist, then you need to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Whe you insert(15,c) and (4,a), I believe you need create a linked list to solve the collision since they have the same key(4). Then Delete(15) will delete both a and c.